# Appending multiple values to an array in Perl6

Tags: arrays, nested, append, raku, flatten

I am looking for a way to append multiple values to an @array. The documentation points out that there is a method called .append that would do that job. but when I am doing something like this:

```
my @array = <a b>;
my @values = 1,2,3;
@array.append: @values, 17;
```

I am getting a nested result:

```
[a b [1 2 3] 17]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to slip the array as Perl 6 doesn't auto-slip ("flatten"), except if it's the *only* iterable in an a argument.

So:

```
@array.append: @values;      # will slip the array as it's the only parameter
@array.append: @values,17;   # does not slip @values
@array.append: |@values, 17; # will slip the @values into @array
```

Instead of `|@values`, you could also `slip(@values)` or `@values.Slip`.

Answer (score 2):

This goes rather to explain what's going on there: Following the [single argument rule](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#Single_Argument_Rule), which applies here and basically says that whatever is passed to an iterator (`append` in this case) is treated as a single argument, `@values,17` is building a list (which would be the *single* argument), since `,` is the list building operator; `append` is applied to every element of the list in turn, without *flattening* it: first to the arran `@values`, second to the number. 
Baseline is: if you handle an iterator stuff with commas, it will build a list out of that turning it into a single argument, instead of making it two arguments and doing

```
(@array.append: <first argument>).append( <second argument> )
```

So if you want to add everything as a single, flat, list, do as @lizmat says in her answer, or do a loop and append every element in turn.